# On-change event for filtering datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a datatable, which has a filter. That filter is year-month. So, the datatable should change, according to the year-month I provide in the filter. First step, I've just tried binding the date-timepicker to the control and check whether the on change event is getting triggered or not. This is how I tried:

```
jQuery("#year_month").datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM' });


                jQuery("#year_month").on("change", function(){
                    year_month(jQuery("#year_month").val());    
                });

                function year_month(year_month){
                    alert(year_month);
                }
```

According to my idea, when ever I change the year-month, I should get the alert. But, I get an error: "TypeError: widget.find is not a function". I get this error on the first click to select the year-month itself. What's wrong with this? What should I do?

Comment: are you using the latest versions of jquery and jquery ui ?

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

Comment: This is what I'm using.

Comment: You might try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).